# removing items from a list based on two properties

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the a list called `orderList` of type `Order` which has two properties. The list looks something like below.

```
 Id      Status
 123     Good
 878     Good
 432     Good
 123     Void
```

What I would like to do is to remove any orders that have a Status which is void and any Good orders which have the same Id as a void order. So the result would give me,

```
 Id      Status
 878     Good
 432     Good
```

What is the best way to do this? Is it just getting a list of void orders using linq and then looping through this new list to remove Good orders which share the same Id?

Comment: I would be good if you show what you have so far ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can group and filter later, and flatten the groups at the end:

```
var result= list.GroupBy(e=>e.Id)
                .Where(g=>g.Any(r=>r.Status=="Good") && g.All(r=>r.Status!="Void"))
                .SelectMany(g=>g);
```

Comment: @mybirthname, oh I just saw an error in my solution, thanks, it's already fixed

Answer (score 1):

So you need to group first by your `ID`, after that specified your data and create new Field Remove which should be true if you have any Status `Void` in your group status collection. After that take objects only where the `Remove` is false and in the end create your `RootOrder`.

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.ID)
            .Select(x => new { ID = x.Key, Status = x.FirstOrDefault().Status, Remove = x.Any(y => y.Status == "Void") })
            .Where(g => g.Remove == false)
            .Select(r => new RootOrder { ID = r.ID, Status = r.Status }).ToList();
```

Full code example: [**dotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rtkfoD)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be grouping, filtering and flattening the remaining groups - If you want a more 'literal' query you can try the following:

First filter out all of the non-`Good` `Orders` using [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
orderList = orderList.Where(x => x.Status == Status.Good)
```

Then filter out all of the remaining `Orders` for which there are non-`Good` `Orders` in `orderList` containing the same `Id` using [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
.Where(x => !orderList
    .Any(y => y.Status == Status.Void && y.Id == x.Id)
```

Finally, use the `ToList()` to take the returned `IEnumerable` as a `List`:

```
orderList = orderList
    .Where(x => x.Status == Status.Good)
    .Where(x => !orderList
        .Any(y => y.Status == Status.Void && y.Id == x.Id)
    .ToList();
```